# Wrong syntax query SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to select a user with a particular name:

```
mysql_query('select * from user where screen_name='.$userName.'');
```

Anyone can help me where I'm wrong?

Comment: `mysql_query("select * from user where screen_name='".$userName.'");` or better use Prepared Statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes wrong sql :

```
mysql_query('select * from user where screen_name="'.$userName.'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("select * from user where screen_name = '".$userName."';");
```

Better (in my mind)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `screen_name` = '".$userName."';";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Even better - use mysqli....

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql_query("select * from user where screen_name='$userName'");
```

try that.....